# Django Datetimepicker change icons

Tags: django, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Django-boostrap3-datetimepicker use "Glypicon".
Does anyone know it is possible change to Font awesome ?

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I found boostrap-datetimepickser.js, but i don't know which place paste your code

Here i upload my boostrap-datetimepickser.js
https://ufile.io/24jac